# How Node js app register to Spring eureka?

Tags: node.js, spring, netflix-eureka

Is it possible to  implement node js app as a spring eureka client? I use eureka-js-client to register spring eureka server, it always response 404 error.

Answer (score 6):

Check out the [README](https://github.com/jquatier/eureka-js-client#404-not-found-errors-from-eureka-server) of [eureka-js-client](https://github.com/jquatier/eureka-js-client) for some helpful tips on this error.

If you are using Spring Cloud you'll likely want to set `servicePath` under the `eureka` section of your client configuration to `/eureka/apps/`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes It is possible, Check these three files in [repo](https://github.com/mtheus/eureka-js-client/tree/master/examples/service-springcloud).

```
eureka: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8761,
    servicePath: '/eureka/apps/'
  }
```

To this part in server.js you have to a add your own details (port and host details, If you have hosted in seperate machine you should add that machine's  IP address as host)

Answer (score 1):

Eureka server can be configured for non-jvm applications such as the nodeJS using the `sidecar` concept. Essentially, this concept differs from the previous answer in it requires a small spring application (the sidecar) to directly discover Eureka  server, handle registration and health checks. Additionally, the nodeJS application must have a designated endpoint known  to the sidecar application for periodic `health check status updates`. A possible message provided from this `health check uri` could be:

```
{
   "status":"UP"
}
```

You can take a look at this [git repo](https://github.com/BarathArivazhagan/spring-cloud-sidecar-sample) for a sample implementation. For detail description of the sidecar concept, take a look at this [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__polyglot_support_with_sidecar.html). The diagram below (taken from this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/BarathArivazhagan/spring-cloud-sidecar-sample) above) provides a graphical explanation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by following the configuration used here https://gist.github.com/zilehuda/a825bddf38d7f40b1640aa669ca52beb, then I would call:

```
eurekaHelper.registerWithEureka(SERVICE_NAME, PORT);
```

Credit goes to [@zilayhuda](https://medium.com/@zilayhuda)

Answer (score 0):

Working example already present in the github
you can refer it
https://github.com/zilehuda/eureka-zuul-nodejs-microservices/tree/master/user-service

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33853972)